# How to re Load mysql table when refreshing the page

Tags: node.js

I havce this simple code, when i run this on browser, first time mysql table loads, after that when i refresh the page it does not load till i kiill the process and re run it.
I am trying to refersh the page every 60 seconds so that it will get new updates from the table automatically.
How can i do this ?

I created the Pool, and showing the mysql result in a table.
its shows only once , after that when i refresh the page, it does not update

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'alerts',
  charset: 'utf8'
});


var reo ='<html><head><title>POWER CUT ALERT</title></head><body><h1>POWER CUT ALERT</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';


function setResHtml(sql, cb){
  pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
    if(err) throw err;

    con.query(sql, (err, res, cols)=>{
      if(err) throw err;

      var table =''; //to store html table

      //create html table with data from res.
      for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        table +='<tr><td>'+ (i+1) +'</td><td>'+ res[i].timestamp +'</td><td>'+ res[i].device_id +'</td></tr>';
      }
      table ='<table border="1"><tr><th>Nr.</th><th>Timestamp</th><th>IMEI NO</th></tr>'+ table +'</table>';

      con.release(); //Done with mysql connection
      con.destroy();

      return cb(table);
    });
  });
}

let sql ='SELECT * from alerts';

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  setResHtml(sql, resql=>{
    reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
});



server.listen(8080, ()=>{
  console.log('Server running at //localhost:8080/');
});
```

if i refresh the page, new data should show up .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `reo` at top level, then replacing `{${table}}` the first time your method runs, leaving it changed forever. You need to do this in a new variable instead. To fix it, replace this:

```
  setResHtml(sql, resql=>{
    reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
```

with something like this:

```
  setResHtml(sql, resql=>{
    var reo2 = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo2, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
```

Comment: one quick question, if want to refresh the page every 60 seconds, where shall i put that ?  
Thanks

Comment: @alammd That's completely unrelated to your original question, and as such, shouldn't be asked in a comment on it.

Comment: Sure , I will create a new one